# Validating JSON Object

Tags: python, json, validation

In my code, I'm creating a JSON object and pulling in values from a secondary source. I want to make sure that there are no scenarios in which the values would break proper JSON syntax so I'm attempting to validate it. I am not able to use `jsonschema` in my environment so I can not use the `validate` function from `jsonschema`.

This is my schema:

```
[
    {
        "attributes": {
            "value1": "string",
            "value2": "string",
            "value3": "number",
            # more similar lines
            "value10": "string"
         }
    }
]
```

I've created a JSON object called `sample_json` using dummy values. How am I able to validate `sample_json` against my schema without using `jsonschema` ?

Comment: As long as `json.dump()` succeeds, it should be proper JSON synta.

Comment: JSON schema isn't about syntax, it's about datatypes and documenting the semantics.

Comment: You're correct, that's what I meant. Syntax was a bad choice of words. I was overthinking it. I will use `dumps` and contain it within a `try/catch` statement. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do json.dumps() to check that the syntax is valid. Then after conversion to dict with json.loads() try to access all the required elements by name in a try block and catch the exception using except KeyError.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe dataclasses?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from validated_dc import ValidatedDC


@dataclass
class MyData(ValidatedDC):
    field1: str
    field2: int


data = {
    'field1': '1',
    'field2': 2
}
instance = MyData(**data)
assert instance.is_valid()

data = {
    'field1': 1,  # Error - not str
    'field2': '2' # Error - not int
}
instance = MyData(**data)
assert not instance.is_valid()
print(instance.get_errors())
# {'field1': [BasicValidationError(value_repr='1', value_type=<class 'int'>, annotation=<class 'str'>, exception=None)], 'field2': [BasicValidationError(value_repr='2', value_type=<class 'str'>, annotation=<class 'int'>, exception=None)]}
```

https://github.com/EvgeniyBurdin/validated_dc